# How to properly pass run-time determined command line switches that include *'s in bash?

Tags: bash, rsync

I am writing a simple script that rsync's a remote site to my local computer, and dynamically generates `--exclude=dir` flags depending on what option is specified on the command line.

```
#!/bin/bash -x

source="someone@somewhere.org:~/public_html/live/"
destination="wordpress/"

exclude_flags='--exclude=cache/* '

if [ "$1" == "skeleton" ] ; then
    exclude_flags+='--exclude=image-files/* '
fi

rsync --archive --compress --delete $exclude_flags -e ssh $source $destination
```

I'm running into trouble when I try to interpolate the $exclude_flags variable on the last line.  Since the variable has spaces in it, bash is automatically inserting single quotes before and after the interpolation. Here is the command which bash tried to execute (the relevant output of /bin/bash +x):

`+ /usr/bin/rsync --archive --compress --delete '--exclude=cache/*' '--exclude=image-files/*' -e /usr/bin/ssh someone@somewhere.org:~/public_html/live/ wordpress/`

As you can see, bash has inserted a bunch of single quotes around the individual tokens of $exclude_flags, which is causing rsync to choke.

I have tried:

1. What I have listed above.
2. Putting it in double quotes `... "$exclude_flags" ...`.  This almost fixes the problem, but not quite.  The single quotes only appear around the full content of $exclude_flags, rather than around each token.
3. Making $exclude_flags an array, and then interpolating it using ${exclude_flags[@]}.  This gives the same output as #2.
4. Wrapping the whole rsync line in back-tick quotes. This gives the same output as #1.

Any ideas?  This seems like a really simple and common problem in bash, so I'm sure that I'm doing something wrong, but google didn't help at all.

Thank you.

Comment: What do you mean by rsync "chokes"? You actually have the correct syntax. Btw for easy testing you can use the `--dry-run` flag.

Comment: The single quotes are only for display purposes using the `-x` option; they aren't physically present in the command line.

Answer (score 0):

The proper way to store multiple command-line options in a variable in `bash` is to use an array:

```
source="someone@somewhere.org:~/public_html/live/"
destination="wordpress/"

options=( '--exclude=cache/*' )
if [[ "$1" == "skeleton" ]] ; then
  options+=( '--exclude=image-files/*' )
fi

rsync --archive --compress --delete "${exclude_flags[@]}" -e ssh "$source" "$destination"
```